# What do those different separators of arguments mean?

Tags: notation

While studying the [wikipedia article about elliptic integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind), I encountered this notation, which I do not understand.

$$F(\varphi,k) = F(\varphi \,|\, k^2) = F(\sin \varphi ; k) = \int_0^\varphi \frac {d\theta}{\sqrt{1 - k^2 \sin^2 \theta}}$$

What do those separators

- $F(\cdot,\cdot)$
- $F(\cdot|\cdot)$
- $F(\cdot;\cdot)$

of the arguments of $F$ mean explicitly?

Comment: It's a way of avoiding confusion when you have a family of functions that can be parametrised in different ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was too fast in asking the question. Further reading demystified the nature of the separators. Sorry for my impatience. I quote [from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind):

> In this notation, the use of a vertical bar as delimiter indicates
>   that the argument following it is the "parameter", while the backslash
>   indicates that it is the modular angle. The use of a semicolon implies
>   that the argument preceding it is the sine of the amplitude. So
>   $$F(\varphi, \sin \alpha) = F(\varphi \,|\, \sin^2 \alpha) = F(\varphi \setminus \alpha) = F(\sin \varphi ; \sin \alpha)$$